# Need help converting MVVM commanding Logic to Caliburn.Micro

Tags: .net, mvvm, caliburn

I have a behavior that was created to work with plain vanilla MVVM and I would like some guidance on how to make it work with Caliburn.Micro.

My Behavior is as follows:

```
public class DropEventBehavior : Behavior<DragSource>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.Drop += AssociatedObject_Drop;    
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.Drop -= AssociatedObject_Drop;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Drop(object sender, DropEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropEventCommand != null)
            DropEventCommand.Execute(e);
    }

    #region Command

    public ICommand DropEventCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DropEventCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DropEventCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DropEventCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DropEventCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DropEventCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof    (DropEventBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion
}
```

This is the relay command:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{

    #region Declarations

    readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
    readonly Action<T> _execute;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RelayCommand&lt;T&gt;"/> class and the command can always be executed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RelayCommand&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {

        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public virtual Boolean CanExecute(Object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public virtual void Execute(Object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
   <Grid.Resources>
      <local:MainPageViewModel x:Key="MainPageViewModel"/>
    </Grid.Resources>  

   <ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source1}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <sdk:Label Content="{Binding Name}">
                        <ig:DragDropManager.DragSource>
                            <ig:DragSource IsDraggable="True">
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <local:DropEventBehavior
                                        DropEventCommand="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainPageViewModel}, Path=DropCommand}"/>
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </ig:DragSource>
                        </ig:DragDropManager.DragSource>
                    </sdk:Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ig:DragDropManager.DropTarget>
                <ig:DropTarget IsDropTarget="True"/>
            </ig:DragDropManager.DropTarget>
   </ListBox>
```

This is how the command is handled in the view model:

```
public class DragDropEventCommands
{
    public ICommand DropCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<DragDropEventArgs>(
                new Action<DragDropEventArgs>(
                    (e) =>
                    {
                        Data dragData = (e.DragSource as Label).DataContext as Data;
                        ObservableCollection<Data> dropSource = (e.DropTarget as ListBox).ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Data>;

                        if (dragData != null && dropSource != null)
                            dropSource.Add(dragData);
                    }));
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get to the following:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <local:DropEventBehavior cal:Message.Attach="[Event DropEventCommand] = [Action HandleDropEvents($source, $eventArgs)]"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I am not adverse to using triggers. It didn't work out in this case because the DropEvent is not a routed event.

If anyone can me figure this out I would appreciate it.

THANKS :-)

Answer (score -2):

Have you found these, and does it help?
I'm sure I remember reading something, but can't remember fully.

Did these quick searchs to see if I could remember, and think this it it.

- [Can I use Caliburn to bind to RoutedCommands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364919/can-i-use-caliburn-to-bind-to-routedcommands)
- https://gist.github.com/GraemeF/500370
- [How can I bind key gestures in Caliburn.Micro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181310/how-can-i-bind-key-gestures-in-caliburn-micro)
- [How do you bind to a command property with caliburn.micro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680828/how-do-you-bind-to-a-command-property-with-caliburn-micro)
- http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/222164
- http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/250844
- http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/247535
- http://calmicrofce.codeplex.com/